# how to merge pdf FileResponse from different views into one pdf file

Tags: python, django, pypdf

Here I am returning pdf file from first function,

```
def file_pdf_to_merge(id):
       pdf=SimpleDocTemplate(file_name(id))
       flow_obj=flow_obj_for_display(id)
       pdf.build(flow_obj)
       return 
       FileResponse(pdf,as_attachment=False,content_type='application/pdf')
```

and second file is from this function

```
def file_get_ri_pdf(id):
   #response = FileResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
   #response['Content-Disposition'] = file_name(id)
   pdf=SimpleDocTemplate(file_name(id))
   flow_obj=flow_obj_ri_display(id)
   pdf.build(flow_obj)
   
return FileResponse(pdf,as_attachment=False,content_type='application/pdf')
```

Here both views are called

**Method 1**

```
def pdf_(request,id):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/pdf')  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ReceiptRequest.pdf"'  
    estimate_pdf=file_pdf_to_merge(id)
    reimbInv_pdf=file_get_ri_pdf(id)
    pdfs=[estimate_pdf,reimbInv_pdf]
    pdfMerger=[]
    for pdf in pdfs: 
        with open(pdf, 'rb') as f: 
            pdfMerger.append(f) 

    with open(response,'wb') as f:
    pdfMerger.write(f) 
    return response
```

**Method 2**

```
def pdf_(request,id):
        output='Jazz_Receipt_Request.pdf'
        pdfMerger=PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
        pdfMerger.append(file_pdf_to_merge(id))
        pdfMerger.append(file_get_ri_pdf(id))
                
    
        with open(output, 'wb') as f: 
            pdfMerger.write(f) 
    
        return output
```

I have tried both methods non of them has worked.

Here is stacktrace

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\KHSystemDir\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner 
                response = get_response(request) 
…
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\KHSystemDir\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 179, in _get_response 
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
…
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\KHSystemDir\KHSystemProject\JazzReceiptNumberRequest\views.py, line 53, in pdf_ 
    pdfMerger.append(file_pdf_to_merge(id)) 
…
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\KHSystemDir\KHSystemProject\Estimate\views.py, line 261, in file_pdf_to_merge
```

I tried different ways but none of them is so far successfull

Comment: getting any errors?

Comment: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'seek' if I use Method 1

Comment: show traceback, and what about second method?

Comment: Edit your PDF-generating functions to just return the PDF object, not a response wrapping it...

Comment: @Janson in first method with  ```pdfMerger.write(f)``` does it save files locally ?

Comment: No i am not saving locally, I am virtually generating pdf and merging together. @Sumithran